Problem with translation while calibrating cameras for stereo vision
I am trying to build a stereo vision camera, yet I am experiencing problems with the translation values I receive through my calibration. My test set up consists of two cameras with are aligned alongside the same horizontal and vertical axes via a spirit level. I conducted the calibration of the single cameras before repeating the calibration process for the pair of cameras. While the rotation values indicate that there is no twist, the translation values appear to be odd.
Calibration Values for a single camera:
- RMSE: 0.47206375111156695
- camera matrix: [[1.05455327e+04 0.00000000e+00 2.04666996e+03][0.00000000e+00 1.05523001e+04 1.56900946e+03][0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
- distortion coefficients: [[-1.67739387e+00  2.35036391e+01 -3.92782040e-02 -3.64264221e-02 -2.76479560e+02]]
- rotation: (array([[ 0.11922471],[-0.09104406],[-0.02655682]]), array([[ 0.13442674],[-0.08707085],[-0.00991447]]), array([[ 0.13209984],[-0.08916987],[-0.010373  ]]), array([[ 0.14978389],[-0.04621664],[-0.00446546]]), array([[ 0.150362  ],[-0.05903345],[-0.00110768]]), array([[ 0.1539541 ],[-0.05918886],[-0.00067417]]), array([[ 0.14892113],[-0.05905072],[-0.00113396]]), array([[ 1.50614552e-01],[-6.33202026e-02],[ 1.01380618e-04]]), array([[ 0.16659327],[-0.04408298],[ 0.04787714]]), array([[ 0.15746244],[-0.04612867],[ 0.03853407]]), array([[ 0.1513342 ],[-0.04390217],[ 0.03889583]]), array([[ 0.15260579],[-0.04453505],[ 0.03866409]]), array([[ 0.15143292],[-0.04571785],[ 0.03867434]]), array([[ 0.14978773],[-0.04303951],[ 0.03923211]]), array([[ 0.14866648],[-0.04494272],[ 0.03920455]]), array([[ 0.16726846],[-0.01945002],[-0.44076573]]), array([[ 0.16930571],[-0.02084982],[-0.44065037]]), array([[ 0.17066226],[-0.02194009],[-0.44077002]]), array([[ 0.16889818],[-0.02804023],[-0.47873453]]), array([[ 0.16565894],[-0.03460989],[-0.47835182]]), array([[ 0.16804761],[-0.03232241],[-0.47820576]]), array([[ 0.15263113],[-0.02378586],[-0.44597584]]), array([[ 0.15403399],[-0.01985177],[-0.44649023]]), array([[ 0.15302255],[-0.02045575],[-0.4465618 ]]), array([[ 0.124049  ],[-0.04426584],[-0.40037654]]), array([[ 0.12275611],[-0.04085825],[-0.39998904]]), array([[ 0.12491642],[-0.0417997 ],[-0.40015748]]), array([[ 0.14919344],[-0.05685586],[-0.020482  ]]), array([[ 0.12932086],[-0.05105033],[-0.00313007]]), array([[ 0.13906037],[-0.05256883],[ 0.00667095]]), array([[ 0.1840439 ],[-0.04604072],[-0.17101166]]), array([[ 0.18104539],[-0.05554671],[-0.13294328]]), array([[ 0.15735554],[-0.03217485],[-0.14875923]]), array([[-0.01049673],[ 0.02479192],[ 0.00317974]]), array([[0.00688075],[0.01046346], [0.00301547]]), array([[-0.01268747],[ 0.01261543],[ 0.0026706 ]]), array([[-0.04119828],[-0.02084318],[-0.0585937 ]]),
array([[-0.02695686],[-0.06092027],[-0.01656897]]), array([[-0.03231206],[-0.04794565],[-0.01792502]]), array([[ 0.08400465],[-0.24189618],[ 0.07489925]]), array([[-0.04043382],[-0.10516169],[ 0.06191672]]), array([[ 0.07297346],[-0.24044129],[ 0.07100568]]), array([[ 0.04579067],[-0.24170215],[ 0.06714978]]), array([[-0.06746852],[-0.09496888],[ 0.06057794]]), array([[ 0.06521439],[-0.22987481],[ 0.06876375]]), array([[ 0.15082825],[-0.15851571],[ 0.04456248]]), array([[ 0.15386361],[-0.16320691],[ 0.04402626]]), array([[ 0.15206409],[-0.15605756],[ 0.0425495 ]]), array([[ 0.13443975],[-0.17355253],[ 0.03701154]]), array([[ 0.13150309],[-0.17649528],[ 0.03654591]]), array([[ 0.14802427],[-0.18616537],[ 0.16219477]]), array([[ 0.13222317],[-0.22575008],[ 1.01017943]]), array([[ 0.13751941],[-0.23017956],[ 1.00998966]]), array([[ 0.12320878],[-0.22874801],[ 1.00617738]]), array([[-0.0462634 ],[-0.01905937],[ 0.01288051]]), array([[-0.05204744],[-0.01646665],[-0.01962633]]), array([[-0.0445432 ],[-0.02055294],[-0.01975873]]), array([[ 0.18696047],[ 0.09956115],[-1.2132724 ]]), array([[-0.02751465],[-0.10972946],[-1.22382845]]), array([[-0.02887956],[-0.11969909],[-1.22362562]]), array([[ 0.14346734],[-0.11314865],[-0.03482447]]), array([[ 0.14251466],[-0.10010936],[-0.04370644]]), array([[ 0.14445271],[-0.11843323],[-0.04546161]]))
- translation: (array([[ -2.65152476],[  3.68251546],[133.27616075]]), array([[ -2.59203222],[ 4.18776336],[133.24403254]]), array([[-2.59174204],[  4.18699252],[133.20211438]]), array([[  5.16975856],[  4.09019442],[133.20118904]]), array([[  5.16797106],[  4.09376715],[133.24528728]]), array([[  5.1639247 ],[  4.08999757],[133.14888071]]), array([[  5.16859663],[  4.0931488 ],[133.26906927]]), array([[  5.18321287],[  4.1013565 ],[133.32158709]]), array([[ 11.27169602],[  3.75448995],[132.95621952]]), array([[ 11.29442999],[  3.78089401],[133.13832115]]), array([[ 11.30175149],[  3.77925301],[133.23524828]]), array([[ 11.29609075],[  3.77662043],[133.17386048]]), array([[ 11.29928919],[  3.77454119],[133.20134097]]), array([[ 11.30440007],[  3.77153985],[133.28096966]]), array([[ 11.30689123],[  3.77040903],[133.29861719]]), array([[ 10.28567251],[ -3.54768972],[132.90793507]]), array([[ 10.29127097],[ -3.55036936],[132.99556133]]), array([[ 10.285639  ],[ -3.5458442 ],[132.92039868]]), array([[  5.84679415],[ -0.97388226],[133.35820975]]), array([[  5.84557955],[ -0.97508406],[133.32818265]]), array([[  5.84629778],[ -0.9749425 ],[133.32508354]]), array([[  2.04155606],[  1.03902782],[133.30420803]]), array([[  2.04136016],[  1.0393175 ],[133.32640377]]), array([[  2.04091679],[  1.0401602 ],[133.32608093]]), array([[ -1.99022056],[  3.09730935],[133.50941614]]), array([[ -1.99037254],[  3.09640142],[133.53736507]]), array([[ -1.98994401],[  3.09734684],[133.54710336]]), array([[  1.6966513 ],[ -0.27260814],[132.6401305 ]]), array([[  1.66055873],[ -0.32065528],[132.68811306]]), array([[  1.64058984],[ -0.34119895],[132.54449335]]), array([[  6.89411054],[ -2.87089381],[132.03954487]]), array([[  7.80062826],[ -3.11440187],[132.00341684]]), array([[  7.89922375],[ -2.95630777],[132.07541581]]), array([[-13.82285176],[-14.237506  ],[130.46402802]]), array([[-13.83329285],[-14.25082387],[130.52982153]]), array([[-13.82608462],[-14.23633479],[130.43956787]]), array([[-22.15825885],[ -8.31547943],[130.35767534]]), array([[-22.39385883],[ -8.35134035],[130.66083379]]), array([[-22.38186991],[ -8.3464359 ],[130.62973305]]), array([[-25.38848025],[ -4.27494685],[130.58432337]]), array([[-25.51225615],[ -4.24683008],[131.14906942]]), array([[-25.42064781],[ -4.24219405],[130.66156092]]), array([[-25.42765297],[ -4.22223205],[130.62345336]]), array([[-25.50457425],[ -4.22701111],[131.11640631]]), array([[-25.41201539],[ -4.20961062],[130.50722468]]), array([[-11.75899251],[  3.93584954],[131.28901376]]), array([[-11.71667814],[  3.92591624],[131.14442164]]), array([[-11.74389064],[  3.94581379],[131.31203163]]), array([[-11.7764841 ],[  4.02422892],[131.16256324]]), array([[-11.77453061],[  4.02553478],[131.13900465]]), array([[-11.8950897 ],[  3.12298386],[130.91314261]]), array([[ -9.80530361],[ -2.58076827],[130.11853102]]), array([[ -9.80253031],[ -2.56957465],[129.98134507]]), array([[ -9.85161994],[ -2.57983883],[130.29883749]]), array([[-11.65181684],[ -6.75700591],[132.10761977]]), array([[-11.64763827],[ -6.61488469],[131.91724317]]), array([[-11.66554079],[ -6.61475434],[132.04413821]]), array([[ -8.11075142],[ -5.62835464],[131.49675677]]), array([[ -8.08661599],[ -5.60416953],[130.98860136]]), array([[ -8.07910638],[ -5.60066381],[130.85999629]]), array([[ -7.34607585],[ -3.85253434],[131.65148731]]), array([[ -7.34115749],[ -3.80850553],[131.64100267]]), array([[ -7.3337368 ],[ -3.80802649],[131.64023831]]))

Calibration Values for a stereo setup:
- RSME:  1.9589420111388987
- distortion coeffecient left:  [[-1.60187117e+00  1.88732951e+01 -3.42830959e-02 -3.63326713e-02 -2.39243327e+02]]
- distortion coeffecient right:  [[-6.87982431e-01  3.84309992e+00 -2.29715230e-02  3.19935247e-03 -2.46964429e+01]]
- Rotation:  [[ 0.99347998  0.0068146  -0.11380283] [-0.00323486  0.99949502  0.03161074] [ 0.11396078 -0.0310365   0.99300034]]
- Translation:  [[  467.10413296] [ -141.50336332] [-1253.30375941]] 

What I tried so far:
I tried to solve the problem by rectifying the images and while it worked for some, like scene 33, but others, like scene 1, became very distorted.
Scene 1:

left and right image of scene 1 with key points
left image of scene 1 with epilines
left image of scene 1 rectified

Scene 33:

left and right image of scene 33 with key points
left image of scene 33 with epilines
left image of scene 33 rectified

